# Why is my plugin not getting added in ckeditor4-react?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor4.x

So, I am trying to add this MathType https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wiris/mathtype-ckeditor4
plugin like this:

```
<CKEditor
          // onBeforeLoad={CKEDITOR => (CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true)}
          onBeforeLoad={CKEDITOR => {

            CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(
              "ckeditor_wiris",
              "../node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-ckeditor4/",
              "plugin.js"
            );
            CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
              config.extraPlugins = "ckeditor_wiris";
              // Allow MathML content.
              config.allowedContent = true;
              config.height='80px'
              console.log('from editorconfig')
            };
            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

            console.log(CKEDITOR);
          }}

          data={explanationData}

          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = event.editor.getData();
            handleExplanationEditor(data);
          }}

        />
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't use `../node_modules/@wiris/mathtype-ckeditor4/` path to access the local file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64613858/8443899 check this answer to integrate mathtype plugin in ckeditor4 locally.